# Join two tables with two identical columns

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: Log and Location, there is no relationship between the two. However in each table there are columns X and Y. I would like to make a query selecting the rows having the corresponding X and Y columns of the two tables with the requirement that the condition is just checked at the log table.

> Log table: Id, X, Y
>
> Table Location: X, Y, Address

WHAT I NEED:

```
|    ID      X         Y       Address   |
|    1      123        854       50      |
|    2      478        697       60      |
```

Comment: If there are x and y values that are the same in both tables then there is a relationship between the 2 tables so I am a bit puzzled you think there is no relationship. It would be useful if you provided sample data as text in the question.

Comment: It's two separate tables there is no definite relationship within the database between the two

Comment: IF ' there is no definite relationship within the database between the two ' then you cannot successfully join the 2 tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JOIN statement. For example:

```
SELECT 
   log.id,
   log.x,
   log.y
   location.address
FROM log
LEFT JOIN location ON log.x=location.x AND log.y=location.y
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to join the two tables based on common X and Y values. This would do that:

```
SELECT Log.ID, Log.X, Log.Y, Location.Address 
FROM Log, Location
WHERE Log.X = Location.X
    AND Log.y = Location.Y
```